# how to get id of next div using previous id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get id of next element using `jquery`. HTML code is is follow.

```
<div id="sms_message-0"><div id="nl-form-0" class="nl-form"></div>
```

I have tried this,

```
y= $('#sms_message-0').next().find('div').attr("id");
console.log(y);
```

Here `nl-form-0` is dynamic . so i want to get it's id using static id `sms_message-0`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the next element, it's the first child

```
var y = $('#sms_message-0').children().first().attr('id');
```